# Phone App doesn't stay in navigation stack on phone, but does when connected to VS via USB

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

My Phone App doesn't stay in the navigation stack on phone, but does when connected to Visual Studio via USB. When I run it 'to Device' from Visual Studio, I can go to another app and return to my app (which is still in the state I left it) - but when I run it on the phone by itself it closes when I go to another app and come back (via back button). 
    I have a Lumia 928. (Universal app 8.1)
    Anybody else run across this behavior? Any thoughts on what I might be missing. It navigates fine forward and backwards within my app, and when run as a Device from VS, but not alone.

Comment: Maybe your app crashes when it's being suspended (while debuging PLM is disabled)? Have you tried to debug suspension?

Comment: When it is connected to VS, goto suspend state by VS lifecycle event, not from phone. See if it is behaving same as it is behaving when phone not connected to VS. if so then you might get the reason.

Comment: ahaa. I think you're both right. I will follow up and let you know what I find.

Comment: hey did you find the issue?

Comment: still digging, but you're pointing me in the right direction I'm sure. I'll post my fix when I get it figured out (it does crash on suspend - I added an 'entry' page that launches before the hubPage, and I suspect that is where I am messing up the navigation/suspension).

Comment: Yes, It was in the serialization of items during suspension. Some complex items can't be serialized.  I have put a link below. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to serialize an object that serialization doesn't support. I trapped for that error and now the app behaves properly.

This link helped
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e24c556-3758-40d0-bd03-55e193538340/getnavigationstate-doesnt-support-serialization-of-a-parameter-type-which-was-passed-to?forum=winappswithcsharp